# PYWIN32 upgrade via pip -- Error cannot uninstall... installed by distutils...'

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

Now that pywin32 is available in pip, what's the smooth path for upgrading from an earlier (native MSI installed) version to the latest and greatest in PIP?

My PIP won't uninstall the older version, as noted below.

```
======= C:\Users\bobhy
> pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
. . .
pip             10.0.1
pywin32         221
. . .

======= C:\Users\bobhy
> pip install pywin32==223
Collecting pywin32==223
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/9d/f4b2170e8ff5d825cd4398856fee88f6c70c60bce0aa8411ed17c1e1b21f/pywin32-223-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: pywin32
  Found existing installation: pywin32 221
Cannot uninstall 'pywin32'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: Can't you just uninstall the MSI?

Comment: Isn't it kind of obvious? You have *pywin32v221* installed as an *msi*, and you want to install *pywin32v223* as a *whl* (which requires the old version to be uninstalled). *pip* doesn't know to install *msi*s (and it shouldn't). You have to do what `pip uninstall` is for `pip install` for your *msi* installation (which I think is uninstall manually).

Comment: Downgrade `pip` to 9.0.2 (`pip install "pip<10"`), uninstall `pywin32` (`pip uninstall -y pywin32`), restore `pip` to 10.0 (`pip install pip --upgrade`).

Comment: `pip install --ignore-installed`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue: `pywin32` was coming from ActivePython and I was trying to (unsuccessfully) install another module (*win10toast* for what matters) from `pip` and that that module has a dependency to `pywin32`.

The installation had the same issue.

The solution was to add `--ignore-installed`:

```
 pip install win10toast --ignore-installed
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to uninstall the MSI installation via `Control Panel > Uninstall or Change Program`. After that you can install via `pip`.